# Проблема с firebase database

Tags: база-данных, ios, swift, firebase

***Вопрос 1***

Писал я себе приложение и не обращал внимания на отображение фотографий, загружатся и загружаются из **database**. Но тут обратил внимание на то что фотографию загружаются как-то хаотично. Т.е. имея **20 фотографий** в **database** под ключами **image0**, **image01**, **image02...image09**, **image10...image19**, фотографии загружаются в разном порядке, например (фото в приложении как они отображаются):

**1ая фото - photo02.jpg**

**2ая фото - photo18.jpg**

**3ая фото - photo01.jpg и так далее...**

С чем это может быть связано? И как это исправить чтобы фотографии подгружались поочередности как и занесены в **database**?

Если нужна какая-то информация о коде я допишу ее.

***Вопрос 2***

Мое приложение работает на **collectionView** внутри **tableView**. **collectionView** работает в горизонтальном отображении для скрола фотографий, **tableView** работает для отображений постов для скрола вертикально. В одном посте может содержаться до 30 фотографий, например:

**1ый пост** - 2 фотографии, отображает эти 2 фотографии и скролить можно 2 фотографии

**2ой пост** - 10 фотографий, отображает эти 10 фотографий и скролить можно 10 фотографий

**3ий пост** - 20 фотографий, отображает эти 20 фотографий и скролить можно 20 фотографий

Но когда я добавил **4ый пост** который имеет 5 фотографий, 4ый пост почему показывает что есть 5 фотографий, но скролить я могу только 2 фотографии и отображает он только 2 фотографии согласно 1ому посту.

Это может быть проблема с **database** или это уже проблема с кодом?

Буду признателен хотя бы за ответ на один из вопросов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> С чем это может быть связано? И как это исправить чтобы фотографии подгружались поочередности как и занесены в database?

Это связано с тем, что в реляционных базах данных нет такого понятия, как "очередность внесения в базу данных". Порядок загрузки в БД, порядок физического хранения на диске и порядок выдачи - это никак не связанные друг с другом понятия, и ни одна реляционная СУБД не гарантирует такого порядка. Соответсвенно, если вам этот порядок важен, вы должны позаботиться о нем сами. Например, в таблицу с фотографиями добавить поле `photo_number`, которое будет содержать порядковый номер, и заполнять его самостоятельно (из сиквенса, например, если firebase поддерживает такую штуку), а при выборке в явном виде задавать сортировку:

```
select *
  from photo
 where user_id = 123
 order by photo_number;
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо. С этим справился. А по второму вопросу сможете помочь? Если нужна еще какая-то информация или фото или .gif чтобы было понятно в чем проблема, могу добавить к вопросу

Comment: Не, второй вопрос не ко мне, я только по базам данных. А вообще тут такие вопросы лучше по отдельности задавать.